# A question about Hausdorff's distance

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Given two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, the Hausdorff distance between them is defined as
$$
d_H(A,B):=\max\{\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B),\sup_{b\in B}d(b,A)\}
$$
In a textbook on dynamical systems I found the an alternative definition
$$
D_H(A,B)=\inf\{\varepsilon>0:A\subset B^\varepsilon,\,B\subset A^\varepsilon\}
$$
where for any set $C^\varepsilon=\{x\in X: d(x,C)<\varepsilon\}$.

My question is whether both notions are equivalent.

Comment: Just a little detail. This doesn't define a distance (a metric) on the subsets of $X$. Some other hypothesis over the subsets are necessary.

Comment: @jjagmath: I am aware of that. In fact it is a well known fact that $d_H$ is a metric on the collection closed bounded subsets of $(X,d)$. But that is irrelevant for question. I am only concerned on whether $d_H$ and $D_H$ defined equivalent metrics, or furthermore, whether $d_H=D_H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are equivalent definitions. Indeed, let $d$ and $D$ be the distances. By the definition of $d$ then $A\subseteq B^d$ and $B\subseteq A^d$, so $D\le d$. If $D<d$, then there should be $\epsilon <d$ such that $B\subseteq A^\epsilon$ and $A\subseteq B^\epsilon$. But that means $\max_{a\in A} dist(a,B)\le \epsilon<d$ and $\max_{b\in B} dist(b,A)\le \epsilon<d$, a contradiction. So $d=D$.

Answer (score 2):

Not only are both notions are equivalent (as semi metrics on the space of all bounded subsets of $(X,d)$) but they are actually the same thing.

If $D_H(A,B)=\inf\{\varepsilon>0: A\subset B^\varepsilon,\,B\subset A^\varepsilon\}=\infty$ then $\{\varepsilon>0: A\subset B^\varepsilon,\,B\subset A^\varepsilon\}=\emptyset$.  Then for any $\varepsilon>0$, either $A\not\subset B^\varepsilon$ or $B\not\subset A^\varepsilon$. This means that for any $\varepsilon$ either there is $a\in A$ with $d(a,B)\geq\varepsilon$, or there is $b\in B$ with $d(b,A)\geq\varepsilon$. In either case $ d_H(A,B)\geq\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Hence $d_H(A,B)=\infty=D_H(A,B)$.

Suppose $D_H(A,B)=\inf\{\varepsilon>0: A\subset B^\varepsilon,\,B\subset A^\varepsilon\}<\infty$. If $A\subset B^\varepsilon$ and $B\subset A^\varepsilon$, then $\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B)\leq\varepsilon$ and $\sup_{b\in B}d(b,A)\leq\varepsilon$, that is $d_H(A,B)\leq\varepsilon$. Consequently
$$
d_H(A,B)\leq D_A(A,B)
$$
On the other hand, if $d_H(A,B)<\varepsilon$, then $d(a,B)<\varepsilon$ and $d(b,A)<\varepsilon$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, that is $A\subset B^\varepsilon$ and $A\subset A^\varepsilon$. Consequently,
$$D_H(A,B)\leq d_H(A,B)$$